# Pandas - Write a pandas df to the next empty row in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am currently looking for a solution.
Is there a functionality that will look for the next empty row in excel and then paste a pandas df here. (note the pandas df has the same dimensions as the data in excel).

Thanks

**Data in Excel**

| Employee No. | Name | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111111 | John | Spain |
| 222222222 | Mary | Italy |

**Pandas DF I want to write to the excel sheet**

| Employee No. | Name | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 333333333 | Michael | Ireland |
| 444444444 | George | South Africa |

**Final excel worksheet**

| Employee No. | Name | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111111 | John | Spain |
| 222222222 | Mary | Italy |
| 333333333 | Michael | Ireland |
| 444444444 | George | South Africa |

please note I need to write the pandas DF to an excel sheet entitled "Sheet3"

Comment: I ask you to put a reproducible example, or explain better what you want to obtain. I can't even see the excel and pandas df that you apparently "put" in the question

Comment: Do you want to store all rows in a dataframe, starting from the first occurrence of an empty row?

Comment: In this case, instead of finding an empty line, inserting at the end would also be a solution you are looking for? If yes you can concatenate by opening your excel and stored and then concatenate the two dataframes
```df1 = pd.read_excel(f'YOUR_EXCEL.xlsx')

f = [df1, df]
df1 = pd.concat(f)
print(df1)```

Comment: @RafaelMRdeRezende , thank you but I had actually attempted this prior to you recommending it. What happens is it inputs the pandas DF data to the left of the excel data elongating the dataframe, it doesn't insert the data under the existing excel data.

Comment: In this case, do you want to replace the ones that contain some empty fields or simply insert these data below the others?

Comment: I just want to insert the data below

Comment: Use `df1 = pd.read_excel(f'YOUR_EXCEL.xlsx')  f = [df1, df] df1 = pd.concat(f, axis=1) print(df1)`

Comment: axis=1 just adds the data to the right of the existing data

Answer (score 1):

This is tough without seeing your code. I think what Rafael M R de Rezende said is correct.

Say your excel file is like:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[111, 'John', 'Spain'], [222, 'Mary', 'Italy']],
               columns=['Employee #', 'Names', 'Countries'])
```

The new df is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[333, 'Michael', 'Ireland'], [444, 'George', 'S. Africa']],
               columns=['Employee No.', 'Name', 'Country'])
```

checking the shape `print(df.shape)` or `print(df2.shape)` both results in (2,3).

Next: Use `concat` ...

```
df = pd.concat([df2, df])
print(df.shape)
```

and the shape becomes (4,6) because the columns names are not the same. If this is what your experiencing just change above like below you can copy the columns names over.

```
df2.columns = df.columns # copies column names over
df = pd.concat([df2, df])
print(df)
```

The results is:

```
   Employee No.     Name       Country
0       111         John         Spain
1       222         Mary         Italy
0       333      Michael       Ireland
1       444       George  South Africa
```

When saving, I recommend using `df.to_csv(yourfile.csv, index=False)` it is easier to work with, it is what I do.
Reference [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [df.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)